# Would it be bad coding practice to define a singleton in JavaScript like this?

Tags: javascript, singleton

This code works, but I am not sure if it would be considered bad practice to run a function and then overide that function whilst still in the function:

```
(function () {

        var Singleton = function () {
            var singleton = {};
            //...
            // Overide the function:
            Singleton = singleton;
        };

}());`
```

Comment: One should have started replying after the sentence *this code works*...

Comment: It's confusing at best.

Comment: You're not overriding the function, you're overriding the reference to the function. Wouldn't that be confusing to use? The first time other code refers to `Singleton` it has to be called as a function, but then suddenly it stops being a function. How is that useful?

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> This code works

I doubt it.

> but I am not sure if it would be considered bad practice to run a function and then override that function whilst still in the function

It's acceptable when necessary, although a bit confusing, and you never should rely on the fact that the old function is not called again.

What is *not acceptable* and definitely a bad practise is to override a function with an object, like you do. It would have to be called the first time but not for the following accesses. You don't need that `Singleton` function at all, just use the object literal:

```
(function () {
    var singleton = {
        …
    };

    … // use `singleton` here
}());
```